# Zurb Foundation menu - Separate Align for desktop and mobile views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

For my Zurb menu, I want it to be aligned center in desktop view - to do this I used the following code:

```
nav.top-bar {
text-align:center;
}
section.top-bar-section {
display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem is, it also centres the menu in mobile mode.  I would like the mobile mode to stay aligned to the left.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`css media queries`**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). You can do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  nav.top-bar {
    text-align:left;
  }
}
```

***Make sure you add this style below your original style so that it can override it.*** Checkout some [**`media queries for standard devices`**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)